# Find the Itô representation of the following random variable

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion and $T \geq 0$. Find a constant $z_T \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(s,\omega) \in \mathcal{V}([0,T])$ such that $F_T(\omega) = z_T + \int_{0}^{T} \phi_T(s,\omega)dB_s(\omega)$ when $F_T(\omega) = \int_0^T B^3_s(\omega) ds$.

The idea is to rewrite $\int_0^T B^3_s ds$ using Itô's lemma, but it seems like I'm stuck in a loop. We have

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
d(tB_t^3) &= B_t^3dt + 3tB_t^2dB_t + 3t B_t d \langle B \rangle_t \iff \\
\int_0^T B_t^3 dt&= TB_T^3 - \int_0^T 3tB_t^2 d B_t - \int_0^T 3t B_t dt
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now two new terms appeared, $TB_T^3$ and $\int_0^T 3t B_t dt$. If we plug in

$$ TB_T^3 = \int_0^T B_t^3 dt + \int_0^T 3tB_t^2 d B_t + \int_0^T 3t B_t dt $$

everything cancels, yielding $0=0$. Otherwise we can proceed by using Itô on $\int_0^T 3t B_t dt $ to see what we get, but I'm not quite sure if that's gonna give anything. Any hints?

*Edit, solution:*

We have that

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\int_0^T 3t B_t dt = \frac{3}{2}T^2B_T - \int_0^T \frac{3}{2}t^2 dB_t \\
&TB_T^3 = \int_0^T 3T(B_t^2 +T -t) dB_t \\
&\frac{3}{2}T^2B_T = \frac{3}{2}T^2 \int_0^T dB_t
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

by some Itô engineering, yielding

$$
\int_0^T B^3_t dt = \int_0^T (T-t)(3T + 3B_t^2 + \frac{3}{2}(T+t))dB_t.
$$

Comment: If this is true with a constant $z_T$ then it can only be zero because of $\mathbb E[B_s^3]=0$ and $\mathbb E[\int_0^T\phi_T(s)\,dB_s]=0\,.$ Are you sure that $z_T$ is not random?

Comment: That's how the problem is formulated. In the Itô representation theorem, $z_T$ is replaced by $E[F_T]$, and as you said $E[F_T] = 0.$ So the question then becomes to write $\int_0^T B_s^3 ds$ as an Itô integral, correct?

Comment: I wrote my answer is different but in fact it looks same as yours. Not quite. The term $(T-t)T$ is $T^2-Tt\,.$ In my answer this corresponds to $-u(t-u)=u^2-ut$ and your $T$ is my $t$ and your $t$ is my $u\,.$

Comment: The only thing that's different is the sign on the $-u(t-u)$?

Comment: No. It looks like in your notation that term is $(t-T)\color{red}{t}\,.$

Answer (score 1):

Seems I obtain something different which cannot be since the representation
should be unique.

- By Ito,
  $$\tag{1}
  B_t^3=\textstyle 3\int_0^tB_s^2\,dB_s+3\int_0^tB_s\,ds\,.
  $$
- By integration by parts,
  $$
  \textstyle\int_0^sB_u\,du=\textstyle\int_0^s(s-u)\,dB_u\,.\tag{2}
  $$
- By stochastic Fubini,
  \begin{align}
  \textstyle\int_0^t\int_0^sB_u\,du\,ds&\stackrel{(2)}=\textstyle\int_0^t\int_0^s(s-u)\,dB_u\,ds\stackrel{stoch. Fub.}=\int_0^t\int_u^t(s-u)\,ds\,dB_u\,.\tag{3}\\
  \end{align}
- Then, using (1),
  \begin{align}
  F_t&=\textstyle\int_0^tB_s^3\,ds\stackrel{(1)}=3\int_0^t\int_0^sB_u^2\,dB_u\,ds+3\int_0^t\int_0^sB_u\,ds\,du\\[2mm]
  &\stackrel{stoch. Fub.}=\textstyle3\int_0^t\int_u^tB_u^2\,ds\,dB_u+3\int_0^t\int_0^sB_u\,ds\,du\\[2mm]
  &\stackrel{(3)}=\textstyle3\int_0^tB_u^2(t-u)\,dB_u+3\int_0^t\int_u^t(s-u)\,ds\,dB_u\\[2mm]
  &=\textstyle3\int_0^tB_u^2(t-u)+\frac{t^2-u^2}{2}-u(t-u)\,dB_u\,.\tag{4}
  \end{align}